# bitbucket hook not working

Tags: bitbucket, hook, githooks, bitbucket-server

I am working with buctbucket version 4.4.1. When i am trying to run by custom pre-commit hook with stash it gives me error stating that failed to push some references. the hook is written in shell format placed inside pre-receive.d directory of repository. the script when placed inside this directory is executing file but at the end getting failed with below error

! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://@/scm/ht/pre-commit.git'

**here is the debug log of my script**`enter code here`

```
http://mishrav@vklnld1156:7990/scm/ht/pre-commit.git  ! [remote
rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed
to push some refs to
'http://mishrav@vklnld1156:7990/scm/ht/pre-commit.git'
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

OSType=$(uname -s)
echo $OSType

if [ $OSType == "Linux" ]; then
    exec < /dev/tty

    echo -n "Enter Project Name : "
    read PName

    echo -n "Enter Fix Version : "
    read Version
    FVersion=$(echo $Version | sed -e 's/^/\%22/'| sed -e 's/$/\%22/')

    echo -n "Enter Jira issue Number : "
    read JNumber

elif [ $OSType != "Linux" ]; then
    PName=$(git gui--askpass "Enter Project Name : ")
    echo $PName
    Version=$(git gui--askpass "Enter Fix Version : ")
    echo $Version
    FVersion=$(echo $Version | sed -e 's/^/\%22/'| sed -e 's/$/\%22/')
    JNumber=$(git gui--askpass "Enter Jira Issue Number : ")
    echo $JNumber
fi


checkVersion(){

    if [[ $(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $(git symbolic-ref HEAD) | awk -F "/" '{print $1}') == master ]]; then
        echo "On master branch "
        return 1

    elif [[ $(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $(git symbolic-ref HEAD) | awk -F "/" '{print $1}') != master ]]; then

        echo "On feature branch"

        branchVersion=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $(git symbolic-ref HEAD) | awk -F "/" '{print $2}')   

    else
        echo "Branch not present "
    fi


}

pomVersion(){
    if [ $OSType == "Linux" ]; then
        PomVersion=$(git show :pom.xml | xml_grep 'version' --text_only)
    elif [ $OSType != "Linux" ]; then
        PomVersion=$(git show :pom.xml | sed -n 's:.*<version>\(.*\)</version>.*:\1:p')
    fi 

}

checkTotal(){

checkVersion
pomVersion

if [ $OSType == "Linux" ]; then

    TotalIssueLabel=$(curl -u gituser:gituser http://jira:9090/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=$PName+AND+Labels=$FVersion+AND+Key=$JNumber | python -mjson.tool | jq '.total' | sed 's/null/0/' )
        TotalIssuesFix=$(curl -u gituser:gituser http://jira:9090/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=$PName+AND+fixVersion=$FVersion+AND+Key=$JNumber | python -mjson.tool | jq '.total' | sed 's/null/0/')

if [ $TotalIssueLabel -gt 0 ]
then
    JiraValue=$(curl -u gituser:gituser http://xxxxxx/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=$PName+AND+Labels=$FVersion+AND+Key=$JNumber | python -mjson.tool | jq '.issues[].fields.labels[]'| sed 's/\"//g')


    if [ "$PomVersion" == "$JiraValue" ] && [ "$branchVersion" == "$JiraValue" ]; then
                echo "Commit Successfull on $branchVersion 1"
            return 1

    elif [ $(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $(git symbolic-ref HEAD)| awk -F "/" '{print $1}' ) == master ]; then
            echo "commet successful on master branch 1"
    fi

elif [ $TotalIssue -gt 0 ]
    then
    JiraValue=$(curl -u gituser:gituser http://xxxxx/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=$PName+AND+Labels=$FVersion+AND+Key=$JNumber | python -mjson.tool | jq '.issues[].fields.fixVersions[]' | sed 's/\"//g')


    if [ "$PomVersion" == "$JiraValue" ] && [ "$branchVersion" == "$JiraValue" ]; then
                echo "Commit Successfull on $branchVersion 2"
                return 1

    elif [ $(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $(git symbolic-ref HEAD)| awk -F "/" '{print $1}' ) == master ]; then 
            echo "commet successful on feature branch 2"
        return 1

    else 
        echo "No vaules mached 2"
        return 1
    fi

fi



elif [ $OSType != "Linux" ]; then
            TotalIssueLabel=$(curl -u gituser:gituser http://xxxxxxx/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=$PName+AND+Labels=$FVersion+AND+Key=$JNumber | python -mjson.tool | C:/jq/jq.exe '.total' | sed 's/null/0/' )

         TotalIssueFix=$(curl -u gituser:gituser http://jira:9090/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=$PName+AND+fixVersion=$FVersion+AND+Key=$JNumber | python -mjson.tool | C:/jq/jq.exe '.total' | sed 's/null/0/')

if [ $TotalIssueLabel -gt 0 ]
then
            JiraValue=$(curl -u gituser:gituser http://xxxxxx/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=$PName+AND+Labels=$FVersion+AND+Key=$JNumber | python -mjson.tool | C:/jq/jq.exe '.issues[].fields.labels[]'| sed 's/\"//g')

    if [ "$PomVersion" == "$JiraValue" ] && [ "$branchVersion" == "$JiraValue" ]; then
            echo "Commit Successfull on $branchVersion 1"
        exit 1

    elif [ $(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $(git symbolic-ref HEAD)| awk -F "/" '{print $1}') == master ]; then
            echo "commet successful on master branch 1"
    fi

elif [ $TotalIssueFix -gt 0 ]
then
        JiraValue=$(curl -u gituser:gituser http://jira:9090/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=$PName+AND+Labels=$FVersion+AND+Key=$JNumber | python -mjson.tool | C:/jq/jq.exe '.issues[].fields.fixVersions[]' | sed 's/\"//g')


        if [ "$PomVersion" == "$JiraValue" ] && [ "$branchVersion" == "$JiraValue" ]; then
            echo "Commit Successfull on $branchVersion 2"
            exit 1

               elif [ $(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $(git symbolic-ref HEAD)| awk -F "/" '{print $1}') == master ]; then
                    echo "commet successful on feature branch 2"                                    
            exit 1

            else
                     echo "No vaules mached 2"
                     exit 1
                 fi
  else 
        echo "no issues mached"
    exit 1

  fi
fi

}

checkTotal


#def get_git_revision_hash():
#    return subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'])
# In *nix systems, an "exit code" of 0 means
# that execution happened sucessfully, whereas a nonzero
# exit code indicates an error.
#
# In python, you can return an exit code with sys.exit(CODE)
#sys.exit(-1)
```

Comment: what does the hook do? can you add `-x` to bash shebang?

Comment: Hi Yuri, This is used for velidaition for pre-commit but as pre-commit is not supported in stash as it is in git i tried to do this.

Comment: Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: ++ uname -s
remote: + OSType=Linux
remote: + echo Linux
remote: + '[' Linux == Linux ']'
remote: ++ pwd
remote: + pwd=/app/cobraqagsom/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/shared/data/repositories/122
remote: ++ cat /app/cobraqagsom/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket/shared/data/repositories/122/hooks/pre-receive.d/input.txt
remote: ++ awk NR==1
remote: ++ awk -F = '{print $2}'
remote: + PName=TRNXXIII
remote: + echo -n 'Enter Fix Version : '
remote: ++ cat /app/cobraqagsom/atlassian/application-}'

Comment: it checks multiple things from jira and bitbucket and pom fileand matches them. this works fine when using with git

Comment: looks like you hook is interactive. It is better that you will paste the hook content in the qestion

Comment: I have added my cope snip

Answer (score 0):

Your hook is wrong and it exits with status 1, that causes the push to fail. Please refer to the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive). The hook receives in stdin `<old-value> <new-value> <ref-name>`, so you script inserts these into your variables `PName`, `Version` and `JNumber` here

```
if [ $OSType == "Linux" ]; then
  exec < /dev/tty

   echo -n "Enter Project Name : "
   read PName

   echo -n "Enter Fix Version : "
   read Version
   FVersion=$(echo $Version | sed -e 's/^/\%22/'| sed -e 's/$/\%22/')

   echo -n "Enter Jira issue Number : "
   read JNumber
```

You need to change your hook to etxract the issues from the commit message

Comment: if [ $OSType == "Linux" ]; then
        #exec < /dev/tty
        pwd=$(pwd)
        
        PName=$(cat ${pwd}/hooks/pre-receive.d/input.txt | awk 'NR==1' | awk -F "=" '{print $2}')

        echo -n "Enter Fix Version : "
        Version=$(cat ${pwd}/hooks/pre-receive.d/input.txt | awk 'NR==2' | awk -F "=" '{print $2}')
        FVersion=$(echo $Version | sed -e 's/^/\%22/'| sed -e 's/$/\%22/')

        
        JNumber=$(cat ${pwd}/hooks/pre-receive.d/input.txt | awk 'NR==3' | awk -F "=" '{print $2}')

Comment: This is very much fine. the point which i am trying to is to run this script when the user runs he git commit command. the will popup dilog box to enter the values on windows and on linux it will take it from terminal

Comment: Ho can i twik my current script to work as it works in pre-commit